# How to sort an NSMutableArray List of names in alphabetical order in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, sorting, alphabetical-sort

I need to display the list of names which I am getting from the parser. I am getting the NSMutable arrary of list, then i need to display them in alphabetical order.

I tried doing what is given as:

```
NSArray *myArtistArray=[[NSArray alloc]init];
myArtistArray=[artistsList sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:) ];

// error void value not ignored as it outght to be
[myArtistArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[yourMutableArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
[yourArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Comment: i got error as error void value not ignored as it outght to be how can i get sorted that list

Comment: `sortUsingSelector` sorts a mutable array in place and does not return a value.  `sortedArrayUsingSelector` creates and returns a sorted copy of the array.

Answer (score 4):

```
[yourMutableArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  NSArray *arraysort=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"z",@"v",@"a",@"g",@"b", nil];
 NSArray   *sortedArray = [arraysort sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    for (NSString *str in sortedArray) {
        NSLog(@"string %@ ",str);
    }
    NSLog(@"sortedarrayelements %d",[sortedArray count]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[yourArrayName sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```